# Tracking of property changes per property in custom object

Tags: c#

I've searched around but haven't been able to find a solution that adequately solves my problem.

I have an application I'm building with various model classes. Currently, I'm working on the Database layer. My end goal is the following call:

```
public void SomeMethod(ModelObject param)
{
    IEnumerable<IModelObject> results = DatabaseLayer.Get(param);
}
```

Basically, I want to pass my Database layer a model object and use the properties set as parameters to be later constructed in the Where clause of the query.

My problem is pretty simple: Non-nullable types. However, I do not wish to change all of the model property types to

```
public int? intProperty { get; set; }
public DateTime? dateTimeProperty { get; set; }
```

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to differentiate between default values and set values to see what's been changed. Either by way of an attribute or maybe model-specific logic that tracks property set calls by way of constructing a list. I'm pretty against setting them to nullable types.

The pseudo-code for the database Get method is similar to:

```
public IEnumerable<IModelObject> Get(ModelObject param)
{
    //Iterate through ModelObject parameters to find non-default values
    //Write these into a where clause
    //Query and return IEnumerable of serialized results from database
}
```

Let me know if more information is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you set against using nullable types?  That's definitely the way to go given your dilemma.

Comment: `default(int)` returns a default value for the `int` type; same for any other type. It returns `null` for any nullable type. But before you leap off the default-value cliff, I suggest you relent and use `Nullable`/`?` instead, because that's exactly what it's for, and that is *a much lower cliff*.

Comment: @roryap Honestly, there's no reason not to use nullable types. I was just interested in using something clever. Even if it was more work than changing datatypes and fixing type mapping.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to differentiate between a value type's default value and a set value that happens to be the default value.

You will either have to use nullable types, or you'll have to do something clunky like maintain a boolean for each property which gets set when the property value changes.

I'd say use the nullable types; that's what they're there for.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Disclamer: I'm the author of the library that I'm going to suggest to you.</sup>

---

Because of some other requirement I had to develop a library to track any object changes so I implemented [*TrackerDog*](http://matiasfidemraizer.com/trackerdog), which is an [open source project hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/mfidemraizer/trackerdog).

If you want to track changes, it's as easy as following these steps:

```
var config = ObjectChangeTracking.CreateConfiguration();
config.TrackThisType<YourModelClass>();

var trackableObjectFactory = config.CreateTrackableObjectFactory();

var model = new YourModelClass();
var trackableModel = config.CreateFrom(model);

// Now perform changes to the whole trackable model:
trackableModel.Text = "hello world";

// Then you can get what properties have changed whenever you want
// using an extension method to get the change tracker associated to
// your model
var changeTracker = trackableModel.GetChangeTracker();
var changedProperties = changeTracker.ChangedProperties;

// or even unchanged ones:
var unhangedProperties = changeTracker.UnchangedProperties;
```

I believe that you should be able to cover your change-tracking needs with [TrackerDog](http://matiasfidemraizer.com/trackerdog) and if you feel that you need some new feature or enhance an existing one, feel free to fill an issue and we can discuss it there!

You can also [follow this tutorial](http://matiasfidemraizer.com/trackerdog/html/52e40f26-3dfe-47e0-adf1-09233e98f42e.htm) that will explain you all available features step by step.

### About distinguishing value type's default value

TrackerDog will be able to tell you if a property has changed if the value is different than the one that was set during construction-time with a constructor or initializer. If, for example, a property is `int` and it's set with `0`, previous and new value will equal, thus, it hasn't changed at all. BTW, as I said before, you can fill an issue in the GitHub repository, and we can discuss how to implement this requirement.

From my point of view, it would be as easy as being able to tell TrackerDog that you want to consider that a property has changed whenever it's set when the property type is a value type. It wouldn't be hard to implement this feature.

Comment: The TrackerDog link provided above does not work and I'm unable to find any documentation elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: @CoderBang Yeah, I should republish the docs in GH/GL Pages. It's just bulding them with Sandcastle... The library should be still useful and there're few alternatives. I'll need to do my homework!

Comment: @CoderBang In the mean time, you should be able to build the docs cloning the repo and building this project https://github.com/mfidemraizer/trackerdog/tree/v2/TrackerDog.Documentation

Comment: Thanks for the link and for TrackerDog! Great job! :)